# изменение строки php

Tags: php

Подскажите не могу никак реализовать изменения строки, мне нужно динамически изменять URL страницы, например есть такая ссылка http://localhost/repair_washing_machines/atlant/ как мне кодом изменить её что бы получить [http://localhost/repair_washing_machines/мой_текст/atlant/](http://localhost/repair_washing_machines/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82/atlant/) ссылку я получаю динамически потому просто подставить не могу мне нужно именно манипуляция со строкой

Comment: Вам нужно менять URL страницы или в области страницы поменять строку  в виде ссылки?

Comment: parse_url - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 0):

нашел функцию которая нужна была, и решил эту проблему вот так, не знаю на сколько это верно, но работает

```
<?php echo str_replace( home_url("/"), home_url("/").'not-draining/', get_the_permalink()); ?>
```

Comment: [тык](https://cs5.pikabu.ru/post_img/2015/12/04/5/1449210847155432089.jpg)